# Jquery Mobile custom selects & dialogs freeze/crash on android

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm new to jquery and jquery mobile and and having an issue with custom selects (data-native-menu="false"). When I tap to open one, with just 4 options, sometimes it opens as normal, but closes itself a second later, before I've had a chance to choose an option.

Another issue, which perhaps may be related, is that sometimes when I open a dialog (data-rel='dialog') it will not close when I tap the "X" button it provides.

My code validates as HTML 5 and the only custom config I have done is defaultDialogTransition & defaultPageTransition off.

I have it so each form element has a unique ID, as has each page.

Both issues happen with opera and android browsers, on 2.3 gingerbread.

Thanks, Kevin

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>
<title>title</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;' />
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/jquery_mobile_global_defaults.js'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/design/mobile_style.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css' />
</head>

<body>
<div data-role='page' id='homepage'>

    <div class='header'>

        <div class='logo'><a href='/' ><img src='/design/logo.png'></a></div>
        <div class='login'><a href='/php/mobile_login.php' data-overlay-theme='b' data-transition='none' data-rel='dialog' data-role='button' data-inline='true' data-icon='arrow-r' data-iconpos='right' data-theme='a' data-mini='false'>Login</a></div>
    </div>


    <div class='mobile_content'>
    <form data-ajax='true'  method='GET' id='btipdgnkrb_form' action='/php/mobile_search.php'>
<div>
<select data-native-menu='false' onchange='ajaxcreateSubCatSelect("btipdgnkrb");' name='main_catetory_type' id='btipdgnkrb_maincat'>
<option>Career path / role</option>
<option value='CONSTRUCTION'>Construction roles</option>
<option value='DESIGN'>Design roles</option>
<option value='ENERGY'>Energy roles</option>
<option value='GENERIC'>General roles</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id='btipdgnkrb_subcatloaddiv' style='text-align:center;'></div>
<div>
<select data-overlay-theme='b'  disabled data-native-menu='false' name='profession_id' id='btipdgnkrb_subcat'><option data-placeholder='true'>
Select role / category</option></select>
</div>
<div><select name='location_id' id='btipdgnkrb_location' data-overlay-theme='b' data-native-menu='false' data-icon='arrow-d'><option data-placeholder='true' value='0'>Location (optional)
</option>
<option></option>
<option value=37>Ireland</option>
<option value=61>Ulster</option>
</select></div>
<label for='btipdgnkrb_keywords' class='ui-hidden-accessible'>Keywords:</label>
<div><input type='text' name='keywords' id='btipdgnkrb_keywords' value='' placeholder='Keywords (optional)'></div>
<div><input type='submit' data-theme='b' data-icon='search' data-iconpos='right' value='Search'></div>
<div><input type='button' onclick='reset_search_form("btipdgnkrb");' data-theme='c' data-iconpos='right' value='Clear form'></div>
</form>
<p>&nbsp;<p>



    <script src='/js/main.js'></script> 

    </div>


    <div data-role='footer' data-theme='a' > 
    <div data-role='navbar' data-iconpos='right'>
        <ul>
            <li><a data-icon='home' href='/'>Home / Search</a></li>
            <li><a data-icon='plus'   href='#'>Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div> 


</div>







</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about more recents Androïd version?

Comment: Hi, 2.3 is all I have and it still seems pretty common, so I think I need to get it to work on it. But yes will try to get access to other phones to test.